# Apache shutdown unexpectedly XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

I have been creating a website project for the past 7 months and XAMPP has been working perfectly. I went to view my website on my localhost and it said that it could not connect. I opened XAMPP control panel v3.3.0 and Apache would not start.

The error says Apache shutdown unexpectedly. I read online to change the ports which I have done but it is still not working. I checked and saw that port 80 and 443 was not in use elsewhere.

I have tried everything and my project is due next week. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Look in the Apache logs. Use journalctl -xe as well. Use systemctl status apache2. There are lots of ways to review Apache errors.

Answer (score 0):

Common issue expecially after installing Windows 10/11 feature or quality updates.

---

Solution.

Download and install the latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable runtime libraries, choose depending on your PC architecture.

Link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Restart your PC and re-launch Xampp.

This worked for me, trust it will resolve the issue for you too.